# Trying to connect to a rabbit mq

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm new to message queue's and i'm trying to connect to a rabbit mq instance that was setup for me using https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node and i'm definitely on the struggle bus.

I took the example from [here](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/tree/master/examples/tutorials#tutorial-three-publishsubscribe) and i'm trying to plug my values in and I'm getting no where.

Here's the info I was given:

```
Server: myserver
Queue: uinotification
username: myuser
password: mypass
```

Here's my attempt at using [this](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/receive_logs.js) example but I think instead of having to assert the queue i need to bind to it (i think).

Here's the docs for bindQueue: http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/doc/channel_api.html#toc_39

I think i'm confused by the exchange piece.

```
amqp.connect('amqp://myuser:mypass@myserver').then(function(conn) {
    process.once('SIGINT', function() { conn.close(); });
    return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
        var ok = ch.assertExchange('logs', 'fanout', {durable: false});
        ok = ok.then(function() {
            //return ch.assertQueue('', {exclusive: true});
            return ch.bindQueue('uinotification', 'logs', '');
        });
        /*ok = ok.then(function(qok) {
            console.log('qok = ');
            console.log(qok);
            return ch.bindQueue(qok.queue, 'logs', '').then(function() {
                return qok.queue;
            });
        });*/
        ok = ok.then(function(queue) {
            console.log('queue = ');
            console.log(queue);
            return ch.consume(queue, logMessage, {noAck: true});
        });
        return ok.then(function() {
            console.log(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C');
        });

        function logMessage(msg) {
            console.log(" [x] '%s'", msg.content.toString());
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error('err = '+err);
    });
}).then(null, console.warn).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('connect err = '+err);
});
```

Here's the error I get with the above code:

```
Channel closed by server: 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no previously declared queue"
```

Answer (score 2):

A queue has to exist before you can bind to it, thus asserting it into existence first is actually what you need to do before binding to it.

Note that the settings for the queue have to be exactly the same as the ones the queue has been first created with.

Comment: The queue does exist and already contains some messages in it. It's name is `uinotification`.

Comment: You can still assert the queue with the same settings, if the queue truly exists in that exchange with that name and settings, the assertion should be  idempotent and return a successful server response.

Comment: Ohh. But why would there be a bind method then? What would be the point of assert vs bind if assert actually binds to an already existing queue?

Comment: As I understand it, creating a queue doesn't actually bind anything to it, because you might just want to create a queue and publish messages to it from another service and then bind to it from another. Asserting it makes the creation of the queue possible from either end.